# Jquery hasClass method is not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am facing a problem while accessing the class of an input tag. First i was using following line of code and it was returning me false.

```
$('#metaField_932.value').hasClass('hasDatepicker')
```

then i used following line of code and it returned me true

```
$("input[id='metaField_932.value']").hasClass('hasDatepicker')
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening .

Note:There is no id duplication in the code.

Comment: can you post the HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
$("#metaField_932\\.value").hasClass('hasDatepicker')
```

It's because `#metaField_932.value` is selecting element with id `metaField_932` and with class `value`. You have to escape dot character.

Answer (score 4):

Your first line is looking for an HTML element that looks like this:

```
<input id="metaField_392" class="value">
```

whereas the second one is looking for one that looks more like your actual HTML element:

```
<input id="metaField_392.value">
```

Any selector with a `.` in it indicates that it is to search for an element with a particular `class`.

To work around this, I'd advise either just using the second selector, or simply removing the period from the element's `id`, since that makes it rather unclear.

Answer (score 1):

**Escape** `.` by `\` because you are searching for `id` not `class` and `selector` preceeded by a  `.` searches for a `class`  like,

```
$("input[id='metaField_932\.value']").hasClass('hasDatepicker')
```

Or

```
$('#metaField_932\\.value').hasClass('hasDatepicker')
```

Answer (score 1):

The selector `#metaField_932.value` searches for element with id `metaField_932` and class `value`. You need to escape the `.` character as given in answers by others.

Answer (score 0):

First lets analyze the selector that you passed to jquery in the first code

`#metaField_932.value`

If you take a close look at it, it means select the element with id as `metaField_932` and class as `value`. As no such element exists the first code does not return anything

Now for the second piece of code works because its an attribute selector and it does not has such confusion.

As F0G has already explain, you will have to escape the `.` with `\\` so jQuery can interpret the entire selector as an id

Therefore `$("#metaField_932\\.value").hasClass('hasDatepicker')` shall work